# bash script invocation shows inconsistent behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a test script( let's call it test.sh) in bash. and the start of the script has following declaration:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

followed by some code.

Now it shows different results when i invoke it as `bash test.sh` versus `./test.sh`. How is it possible. I thought by default `./test.sh` reads the default shell from the first line of script and invokes it with that. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: It only does that if you don't invoke it with another command.

Comment: If you want the `-e` behaviour in your script regardless of how it was called, use `set -e` instead.

Comment: @choroba thanks, will do that :)

Answer (score 2):

The `#!/bin/bash -e` shebang is only used when you (try to) execute a file (that isn’t a binary executable) as a command. This line informs the kernel which executable should be used to interpret the code in the script. See the [shebang Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for more information.

When you run `./test.sh`, your current shell starts a new Bash sub-process with the `-e` option and this new process is the one that executes the commands in the script file.

When you run `bash test.sh`, you’re explicitly starting a new Bash sub-process (this time without the `-e` option) and it starts executing the commands in the file. When it encounters the shebang in the first line, it just treats it the same as any other comment beginning with `#`. (The shebang is also ignored as just another comment if you `source` the file using `. test.sh`).

To ensure that the Bash shell behaves a certain way, it’s best to use the `set` builtin instead of providing an option when invoking Bash. E.g., to ensure the shell exits when a command returns a non-zero status, you should include `set -e` at or near the start of the script.

---

For more in-depth information about how commands are executed with a Linux kernel, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136550/22812) to *What is the difference between running “bash script.sh” and “./script.sh”* and the [`execve` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).

Comment: Also note differences between using `bash test.sh` and sourcing the file (when you `source` the file, an exit will throw you out of the calling shell, when `bash test.sh` is finished changes in working dir and variables are lost).

Comment: @WalterA I've been there. It's particularly annoying if you're debugging and also `set -u` but the script exits early (before the `set +u` and `set +e` commands). That stopped me using `source` or `.` when developing/debugging shell scripts.  :)

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thanks for clearly explaining the behavior. but my question is still unanswered as to why would i get a incorrect result when executing the script like `./test.sh` and i get the correct result if i run it `bash test.sh` way?

Comment: Hi @AnkitKumar I answered the two questions, *How is it possible?* and *Is my understanding correct?* to the best of my possibilities given the (general) information provided. If you want help debugging a related problem *specific to your script*, it would be better to create a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and use it as the basis for a new, more specific (non-general) question.